# "Device got hanged" or "Device got hung"

Tags: grammaticality, past-tense, past-participles

If i have to report an event that took place earlier, what is better to report, "The device got hung" or "The device got hanged"?

The current status of the event is unknown; it is still happening or not.

What is more appropriate to say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ordinary "principal parts" of *HANG* are

```
Plain form          hang
Past form           hung
Present participle  hanging
Past participle     hung
```

Consequently you must say *the device got hung*.

In fully formal contexts *hanged* is employed for the past form and past participle when people are executed by hanging: *The murderers were hanged*.

Horatio raises a possibility which had not occurred to me, which is that you mean *hang* in the sense of "stop working, cease to function". If this is the case, then you cannot use *got* at all: that's a passive construction, like *be hung/hanged*, but *hang* in this sense is an intransitive verb and therefore cannot be employed in the passive.

Comment: I think this particular case--which is idiomatic jargon--is just "The device hung."

Answer (score 5):

As StoneyB says, "the device got hung" is grammatical.

But if you are talking about a computer or something, it probably doesn't mean what you want it to mean.

If the device "got hung", it implies that there's some person (or other agent or actor) responsible for hanging it. In the usual cases where we talk about a device being hung, we usually like to tell ourselves that the device itself was at fault and not the user, so we say "the device hung".

Answer (score 1):

What we have always learnt is that people/ prisoners are always hanged while the objects like coats, shirts are hung. So I think it would be safe to say the the device got hung.